# Could Google Custom Search crawl a domain with just an IP address?

Tags: google-programmable-search-engine

Our staging site currently does not have a domain name for public access, however we do have access over the IP address (like `xx.xx.xxx.xxx`).

Could we use Google Custom Search for this site without a domain?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing in the [Google Custom Search documentation](https://www.google.com/cse/docs/), including their [URL pattern examples](http://support.google.com/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=71826), states anything in regards to using an IP address. However, Google does crawl and index IP addresses, so it might be worthwhile to try since it is the same search engine.